# Offline map rendering on Android Tab

Tags: javascript, android, json, d3.js, geospatial

I have been trying to render a map offline on an android device. I am trying to use d3 for this and any leads and suggestions will go a long way in helping me out.

Can I use d3 and the geojson/topojson files of the region to plot the map on the browser? However, Is there a way to do this without an app server? As of now d3 reads a json through the function d3.json() which needs an app server in itself. Is there a way in which d3 can read the json file directly from the local file path instead of a URL?

Any other direction to approach this problem will be appreciated. Awaiting your response.

Regards,
Jones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is possible.** I have done something like this.

For me, I used an app server but I pushed the JSON string into the HTML and fetched it directly using JavaScript. The code is something like this:

```
var root = treeData = JSON.parse($('#json').val());

function visit(parent, visitFn, childrenFn) {
//....

visit(treeData, function(d) {
//....
```

Comment: Alright, do you know a free web server app for android. I know about Ultimate Servers but the app expires in 7 days. After which we need to buy the app.

Comment: What kind of server are you talking about? A server that runs on Android or a server that communicates with Android?

Comment: A server that runs on Android.

Comment: I don't think that is the common practice. Yes, you can set up database and local storage on Android but it is not a good idea to run a server on a phone. Why exactly do you need a server on a phone?

Comment: Well, my actual need is to be able to read json data into a javascript d3 function. I can just include the entire file as json variable in the code but i want to know what other options are possible.

Comment: In this case GitHub Pages can do the job. It offers free HTML/Javascript static website hosting, which I suppose includes hosting json files. Just need to upload json file to xxx.github.io and fetch it in Android app using d3.js url function. See [link](https://pages.github.com)

Answer (score 2):

**This is not possible.**

d3.json is meant to load data through HTTP. As a workaround, you could set up a local server to serve the data over HTTP.

Comment: How do I set up a local server on an android device?

Comment: actually, at least on osx and windows you can load json, csv and such files from local directories, depends on the browser if they will be loaded or not (on chrome for example external local files are not loaded, while on safari, internet explorer & firefox they do)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an approach like IndexedDB to cache the json? This way you could load the json into IndexedDB on the first page load or while you have internet connectivity, and then retrieve it from the store when you are offline.